# How precisely can I track distances using the iPhone accelerometers?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Theoretically the accelerometers in an iPhone can be used to track distance using interpolation over time.

What is the estimated error for tracking distances between 1 and 10 meters?

Is there any iPhone app that work as a measuring tape?

Answer (score 15):

From what I've heard, the iPhone accelerometer output is very noisy - most applications that utilize it for any sort of moderate precision work do a lot of filtering and output modification to smooth out the noise.

An iPhone can be placed flat on a table, and the accelerometer will still output a fair bit of data.  I imagine you could certainly use it to measure longer distances (>10m), but I probably wouldn't trust it for high resolution measurements.

Answer (score 8):

The accelerometer chips used in the iPhone have too much noise to be used for accurate distance integration over even short distances with simple movements.  Even if it were a quiet sensor and provided good data, Apple pre-filters the accelerometer in a way that prevents applications from performing a proper integration.

The filtering is useful to lower the terrible noise floor, and to make app developer's lives easier whether they want 1 update per second or 100, but it's irreversible and Apple doesn't provide a way to get the raw data, so any acceleration integration only produces delayed distance with significant overshoot.

This is, of course, on top of the normal problems of using an accelerometer to find distance (removing gravity - which the gyroscope makes much easier - for instance).

Most of the pedometer apps use the accelerometer to count steps and use the GPS to measure distance over longer distances and to calibrate the user's individual step distance.  They do not calculate distance using the accelerometer.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of pedometer apps, so you might check their reviews. Also, in terms of accuracy, here's an answer at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722600/what-are-the-ranges-of-the-accelerator-on-the-iphone).

... and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488088/iphone-gps-development-tips-tricks) implementing a pedometer with around 20m accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

The accumulated error of time integration is too much to measure distance from accelerometers. Even for industrial seismographs, most of them can not practically measure distance, even if filtering is adopted.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post about it. Getting distance with accelerometer and other iPhone sensors without using GPS is definitely possible. Results aren't 100% accurate but usable.

http://www.nomtek.com/scanning-rooms-with-an-iphone/

Comment: Posting links only isn't really very helpful. Links disappear over time, so at least some précis of what the link says would be more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want something like this?

[MagicPlan](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/magicplan/id427424432?mt=8) by Sensopia

Depending on what you want to use that information for, couldn't hurt to reach out to the app developers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the precision of the accelerometer but its precision relative to the time of the measurement.

If you can move the phone from point A to point B in a fraction of a second, you should be able to get a very accurate measurement. If you take a minute or an hour for the same measurement, however, the accuracy will be near zero because of the noise.

Answer (score 0):

12 years later, the technology in Phones has been enhanced such that measurements are more precise and reliable.

The app [SizeUp](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sizeup-a-smart-tape-measure/id1031088133) - a smart tape measure - is one such tool I use.

<sub>**Disclaimer** - I have no financial or other connection to the developer of SizeUp, *My Size Israel 2014 Ltd.*</sub>

Comment: The question was about using the accelerometer for such measurements. That app doesn't do the measurement using the accelerometer.

Comment: The essential question: _"Is there any iPhone app that work [sic] as a measuring tape?"_ TBH/ the technology has vastly improved since the question was posited, and I gave a cogent answer. SizeUp, I believe, employs the LIDAR system (used for Face ID) for its measurements. Perhaps it uses LIDAR in concert with newer-gen accelerometers.

Comment: Image analysis, maybe lidar, probalby not accelerometer. There have been demonstrations that show that lidar does not really add much. Sorry, I don't have a link and am going by memory. I was more interested in lidar when I got my lidar-enabled ipad. In finding out its limitations, I've not really used it.